# How to wait for a call to initialize a variable in Rubymotion?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, rubymotion

Can we make some process wait for a variable to be initialized and then continue?

I have the following code:

```
  def viewDidLoad
    BW::Location.get(distance_filter: 10, desired_accuracy: :best) do |result|
      if result[:error].nil?
        lat = result[:to].latitude
        lng = result[:to].longitude
      end
      BW::HTTP.get("APIURL" |response|
        case response.status_code
          when 200
          parsed_json = BW::JSON.parse(response.body)
          if parsed_json[:tags]
            App::Persistence['tag'] = parsed_json[:tags]
          else
            UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.logged_out
          end
        end
      end
    end    

    def imagePickerController(picker, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: info)
      begin
        App.alert('hello')
      end while App::Persistence['tag'].nil?
    end
    App.alert("Finish")
  end
```

When the photo is taken, there is a possibility that my App::Persistence['tag'] hasn't received the value from the API call yet. Therefore, when the user clicks the 'Next' button, I want to make them wait for App::Persistence['tag'] to get initialized before proceeding.

This does not seem to work and it goes on to alert "finish".

Comment: Could you please add more code showing which thread is supposed to wait and which thread is responsible for the initialization? Multithreading is hard. Multithreading with no context is harder.

Comment: hi @Chandranshu, do you understand my scenario??

Comment: Plesae correct me if I am wrong: You're making an API call on the server when somebody clicks the Next button and you want to show them a rotating wheel to signify that they need to wait. Is it right?

Comment: @Chandranshu yes...so im actually waiting App::Persistence['tag'] to be initialzied

Comment: You need to use a dispatch_semaphore to make your call to the API synchronous. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608375/what-is-the-ios-or-rubymotion-idiom-for-waiting-on-a-block-that-executes-async) for some code. Let me know if that doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: hmm, i don't quite understand the code piece. Is that I have to make my location call become synchronous? When user clicked 'Use' and check it or something?

Comment: Yes, you have to make your __location__ call synchronous. Your question doesn't talk about a 'Use' button but I'm guessing that is where you have to make it synchronous.

Comment: hmm, but hw Im able to do that?? I dont really understand the example they showed which make no sense to me >.<''

Comment: @Chandranshu, and it is because mine is in two separate function. which another function is waiting for the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy solution is to put the post-picking/camera business logic into it's own method, then when the image picker/camera finishes, if the tag is ready, call that business logic method then, if it's not ready, setup KVO to listen out for the tag to change maybe, and store the info from the picker/camera, then once KVO picks up that the tag is ready, it will call your business logic method (or a method that calls your business logic method).

```
attr_accessor :cameraInfo

def doTheThing
  # your business logic, do something with self.cameraInfo
  self.cameraInfo = nil
end

def imagePickerController(picker, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: info)
  self.cameraInfo = info
  if App::Persistence['tag'].nil?
    # setup KVO or some basic loop in another thread or something along those lines
  else
    doTheThing
  end
end
```