# Problems with asynchronous calls using motion-resource and BubbleWrap for Ruby Motion

Tags: rubymotion

I'm trying to follow the example from motion-resource 
https://github.com/tkadauke/motion-resource.  Having difficulty getting the data in the correct format with this asynchronous code:

```
def all_friends(&block)
  Friends.find_all do |friends, response|
    if response.ok?
      puts friends.inspect
      block.call friends
    else
      App.alert response.error_message
    end
  end
end
```

In this implementation I have a user resource that has many friends.  I'm trying to find all the friends for this user with User.current.all_friends

I'm getting an error when the data comes back when I try to iterate through it because its coming back as a BubbleWrap HTTP Query.

```
#<BubbleWrap::HTTP::Query:0xc54c7a0 ...>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Stack Stack overflow question addresses the same problems experienced in this question: [What is the iOS (or RubyMotion) idiom for waiting on a block that executes asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608375/what-is-the-ios-or-rubymotion-idiom-for-waiting-on-a-block-that-executes-async?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what line number your error is coming from.

" undefined method `each' for # "

Have you tried removing this line?

```
block.call friends?
```

Your example appears to come from the docs with this working line of code...

```
User.find_all do |users, response|
  if response.ok?
    puts users.inspect
  else
    App.alert response.error_message
  end
end
```

Hope you figure it out.  It would be easier to troubleshoot if the code was executable.

Comment: I found another StackOverflow question that closely matches my problem: [problems-with-asynchronous-calls-using-motion-resource-and-bubblewrap-for-ruby-m](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608375/what-is-the-ios-or-rubymotion-idiom-for-waiting-on-a-block-that-executes-async) I'm following the example in the docs.  It seems like a common problem but  its a hard one describe in complete detail because it involves multiple RubyMotion packages and the app setup behind it to actually get executable code.